ApolloError, AxiosError
I have a project in React Native with axios, as well as a server in node.js. I launch the project, go to the desired page, there is an error - Error when receiving news: AxiosError: Network Error. When I run index.html referencing localhost in the browser, everything is fine, the data is coming, there are no errors, why is this so?
/news/index.tsx (references server.js (node))
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "expo-router";

export default function NewsScreen(){
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchNews = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/news?category=business');
        setNews(response.data.articles);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error when receiving news:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchNews();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Link href="/signin">
        <Text>Go to registration</Text>
      </Link>
      <FlatList
        data={news}
        keyExtractor={item => item.title}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            <Text>{item.description}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

 NewsScreen;


server.js(node)
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors"); // Connecting the cors package
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json()); // Parsing the request body in JSON format
app.use(cors()); // Using cors middleware to allow all requests

// Handler for GET request to index2.html
app.get("/index2.html", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index2.html");
});

// Handler for GET request to news
app.get("/news", async (req, res) => {
  const { category } = req.query;
  const apiKey = "cc6cda365d534d32afd2d4bfbdd671fa";

  try {
    const { default: fetch } = await import("node-fetch");
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?category=${category}&apiKey=${apiKey}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching news:", error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Error fetching news" });
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});



index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>News App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>News App</h1>
    <select id="category">
      <option value="general">General</option>
      <option value="business">Business</option>
      <option value="sports">Sports</option>
      <option value="technology">Technology</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="getNews()">Get News</button>
    <div id="news"></div>

    <script>
      async function getNews() {
        const apiKey = "cc6cda365d534d32afd2d4bfbdd671fa"; 
        const category = document.getElementById("category").value;
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/news?category=${category}`;

        try {
          const response = await fetch(url);
          const data = await response.json();

          if (data.articles) {
            displayNews(data.articles);
          } else {
            throw new Error(data.message || "Не удалось получить новости");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error when receiving news:", error.message);
        }
      }

      function displayNews(articles) {
        const newsContainer = document.getElementById("news");
        newsContainer.innerHTML = "";

        articles.forEach((article) => {
          const articleElement = document.createElement("div");
          articleElement.innerHTML = `
                    <h2>${article.title}</h2>
                    <p>${article.description}</p>
                    <a href="${article.url}" target="_blank">Read more</a>
                `;
          newsContainer.appendChild(articleElement);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


I tried to look at the documentation, but I didn’t find anything, I also have a similar problem with the Apollo client (ApolloError: Network Error), which uses nest.js-server for the same project

The problem is that the url is using localhost. First you need to learn your ip address and then replace localhost with that address
const IP_ADDRESS = '10.0.0.2'
const url = 'http://${IP_ADDRESS}:3000/news?category=business'



Thank you very much, I added this to the index.tsx
